# Moshi Codegen take longer time since it uses reflection(aka."Class.classForName") to create the generated adapter. Is there a way to avoid this?

Tags: json, kotlin, moshi, codegen

Adapters generated via codegen cannot be added in the Moshi.Builder().add(Type, JsonAdapter). So moshi doesn't know how to create the compile-time generated adapter.
It uses reflection to create them, which adds a significant overhead on low-end devices in terms of latency.

is there a way to avoid this? Or should we just replace this with custom type adapters?

Comment: If you're using Moshi with codegen, there's no need to generate adapters using reflection. Every class you want to use for JSON-serialization should be annotated with `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)` and that's it. No overhead is present in this case.

Comment: @user3738870 Please refer to this https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/860. First comment on this issue - When using the moshi-kotlin-codegen kapt plugin, moshi still uses classname reflection to get the corresponding JsonAdapter at runtime.

Comment: Oh that's true, I didn't know that. I don't think there's a way to completely avoid it, but it's cached so if you call it at startup for every adapter, it should be very fast after that.

Comment: I wanted to optimize it for the startup time itself. Hence I feel Moshi isn't the best option. Only way out of this is to have JsonFactory which knows how to create the adapter, instead of relying on reflection.

Comment: Possibly. You can try kotlinx serialization instead: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization

Comment: You could install the JsonAdapters manually, but you should really measure this on real devices. Class.classForName is extremely cheap and sometimes isn't even called on Moshi users' blocking/critical paths.

Comment: For a highly nested class, I observed high values for parsing. I could prevent reflection by creating a Factory(extended JsonAdapter.Factory) and the time reduced by 50% in release builds on actual devices. Quite happy with the perf of Moshi now.